# Using the strategy pattern if the concrete strategy depends on the concrete parameter type

Tags: c++, strategy-pattern

I'm currently working with a System/Data hierarchy implemented like this:

```
class SystemData
{
}

class SystemDataA : public SystemData
{
  int x;
}

class SystemDataB : public SystemData
{
  float y;
}

class System
{
  virtual SystemData* getData() = 0;
  virtual Result computeData(SystemData*) = 0;
}

class SystemA : public System
{
  // really returns SystemDataA
  SystemData* getData() override;
  Result computeData(SystemData*) override;
}

class SystemB : public System
{
  // really returns SystemDataB
  SystemData* getData() override;
  Result computeData(SystemData*) override;
}
```

In the end there is a controller class which does sth similar to this:

```
void foo()
{
  for(auto& s : systemVec)
  {
    SystemData* data = s->getData();
    FinalResult final = s->computeData(data);
  }
}
```

Whereas now each specific system dynamic_casts back to the concrete type it is able to process. This seems like pretty bad design and I'd like to refactor this into sth more reasonable. My first idea was to just implement the computation algorithm inside the SystemData classes and then just do:

```
SystemData* data = s->getData();
FinalResult final = data->compute();
```

but does it really belong there?
It appears more intuitive to have a separate algorithm hierarchy, probably implemented with the strategy pattern. However then I again have the problem of losing runtime type info of the data because all algorithms get passed the abstract data type and in the end will have to dynamic cast and do nullptr and error checks again. So is it still better to implement the algorithm inside the data classes itself? Can I maybe still implement the hierarchy in a separate module and just add function pointers or a similar construct to the data class? Is there a completely different solution I'm not aware of?

Comment: When I see things like this, I feel the need to shout "OOP MUST STOP!!!". In this particular case, it is clear OOP is simply not applicable here. Every time you need to do a dynamic cast, it means you have a design flaw.

Comment: In here, if your system is producer and consumer of data, you simply need to call a function which returns final result, without trying to store intermediate polymorphic data. I believe, your real code is different from your example, but I do not know your real code, so can't give a better advice.

Comment: Our system classes (should) represent bare hardware interfaces and thus only deliver raw data and not be overloaded with additional logic to further process it. It just has been put this way because you need to know which system the data came from to correctly process it and it's easiest to access this piece of information directly at its source. I still think, the computations should be encapsulated in an own configurable module/hierarchy and fed with the raw data on the controller side.